# Install oVirt Node 4.1.6 on IBM x3650 M3

Tags: centos7, ibm, uefi

I have here a IBM **x3650 M3** Server, with **ServerRaid m5015** controller and two disk as **raid1** configured. Bios firmware is the newest Version, settings a default except VT-D is enabled and I add legacy only to the boot order (this was recommended on other pages).

When I try to install a oVirt Node 4.1.6 (is based on CentOS 7.4) I get one time an installation error, where i says something like: boot installer failed.

But another times I can install it normal, but then the system is not booting. There comes shortly a message:

> /boot/efi/*64.efi not found

and after this the server searches for more boot devices.

I try already to disable all uefi options, installing on raid0, both with no success. Some pages says I should change the /boot/efi partition to vfat, but in this CentOS version this is not possible.

Any idea how I get this to work?

**Edit:** I found out that this belongs to oVirt Node. When I install a full CentOS 7.3, the boot process runs normal...